# Open Office JS Template in same Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, vsto, exceljs, office-2013

I would like to open an standalone Excel JS Application as an action pane through my existing VBA Macro or VSTO Application Ribbon in same excel environment/file instead of new excel file/sheet.

Trying to explain in different way:

I already have developed VSTO application which has got various ribbons, now I like to have standalone Excel JS application to be opened in that active excel sheet instead of popping new excel file.

Version: Office 2013

Thanks,

Pawan

Comment: I don't think it's possible to programmatically display an Office JS add-in. The user should be able to use the "My Add-ins" tool to work with such an add-in while your VSTO add-in is running...

Comment: It means user have to go to Insert-> My Apps -> Ans get it through where it is hosted after setting in Trusted Catalog